# Python - Handling an nth line hop with readlines()

Tags: python, readlines

I'm having a go at a fixing a broken lib that I want to use on Github.

I have locally "fixed" the problem. but I don't think its a very clean method...

I'm poking the WARC library by the internet archive, and spcifically the arc.py part (https://github.com/internetarchive/warc/blob/master/warc/arc.py).

Since the lib was written, the tools that make the ARC files have changed a bit, and as a result, the builtin parser fails, as its not expecting to see some metadata in the file.

My local fix looks like this:

```
    if header.startswith("<arcmetadata"):
        while not header.endswith("</arcmetadata>\n"):
            header = self.fileobj.readline()
        header = self.fileobj.readline()
        header = self.fileobj.readline()
```

And I'm not sure that my calling of `readlines()` twice to strip of the next two empty lines (containing `"/n"` is the cleanest way of advancing through the fileobject.

Is this good python? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks like a copy/paste error. There is nothing wrong with using `.readline()`, just document what you are doing:

```
# skip metadata
if header.startswith("<arcmetadata"):
    while not header.endswith("</arcmetadata>\n"):
        header = self.fileobj.readline()
    #NOTE: header ends with `"</arc..."` here i.e., it is not blank

# skip blank lines
while not header.strip():
    header = self.fileobj.readline()
```

btw, if the file contains xml then use an xml parser to parse it. Don't do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Although there's nothing inherently wrong with what you're doing, it might be more semantic to write:

```
next(self.fileobj, None)
```

without a variable assignment to signify that you are tossing the next line.

Comment: [don't mix file methods such as `.readline()` (that is used in `arc.py`) with access to the file as an iterator (`next()`)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4762262/4279).

Answer (score 0):

[itertools](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html) may be of use here

```
from itertools import islice, dropwhile
if header.startswith("<arcmetadata"):
    fileobj = dropwhile(lambda x: not x.endswith("</arcmetadata>\n"), fileobj)
    fileobj = islice(fileobj, 2, None)
```