# Python: Function to skip comment lines of open file and pass file object with current line

Tags: python, class, file-io

I am trying to write some Python code to edit some (existing) input and output files for a particular piece of software. All the files I'm interested in may start with comment line(s) whose first character is # (number of comment lines unknown).

I always want to skip those comment line(s) to read/store important text. Thus, I'd like to create a function that, for a file object that is open in read mode, it will skip the comment lines such that the next call to read from the file object is at the first non-comment line of the file. Currently I am trying to create a class and then use the skip_comments() method (see code below):

```
import os
class FileOperations:

    def __init__(self, directory, filename):
        self.directory = directory
        self.filename = filename
        self.filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directory,filename))
        self.fo = open(self.filepath,'r')

    def skip_comments(self):
        """ Passes the current position to the location of the first non-comment 
        line of self.fo"""

        for line in self.fo:
            if not line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
                break
        print line ## Just to check if in correct spot
```

Instantiating a class object works and I can do normal object file operations like read() and seek():

```
In [47]: fh = FileOperations('file_directory','file.txt')`
In [48]: fh.fo.read(10)
Out[48]: '#This file'`
In [49]: fh.fo.seek(0)
```

But when I try to use the skip_comments() method and then read from the object file I have problems:

```
In [50]: fh.skip_comments()
20 740 AUX IFACE AUX QFACT AUX CELLGRP

Out[50]: <open file '... file_dir\file.txt', mode 'r' at 0x0000000008797D20>
In [51]: fh.fo.read(10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-20f04ae797fe> in <module>()
----> 1 fh.fo.read(10)

ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Can someone help me fix this bug or suggest a better way of doing this? Thank you!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762262/is-it-safe-to-mix-readline-and-line-iterators-in-python-file-processing) explains the reason for the error. Basically, you can't mix `f.read()` with `for line in f` because `next(f)` (which is called when you use iteration) internally uses a read-ahead buffer to improve performance, but this isn't compatible with using `read` or `readline`, because they don't know about the read-ahead buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is turn the `skip_lines()` function into a generator. The generator below yields non-comment lines from the filename you've passed to it.

So:

```
def skip_comments(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line.strip().startswith('#'):
               yield line

#then, to use the generator you've just created:
for line in skip_comments(filename):
    #do stuff with line

#if you want all the lines at the same time...
lines = list(skip_comments(filename))
#lines is now a list of all non-comment lines in the file
```

**EDIT**: A faster (and denser) version would be `skip_comments = lambda filename: (line for line in open(filename, 'rb') if not line.startswith('#'))`. This uses a generator expression which is a fair bit faster (saves about 1/3 of the time on my machine).

Comment: why not `if not ...: yield ...` and drop the else?

Comment: @AaronHall: Makes sense. I was thinking along the lines of making it more obvious that the use of `break` was wrong.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi: I went off to learn about generators and ended up more confused. Can you extend your example with how to actually do what I want. In other words: given your generator skip_comments, how do I apply it and then perform some other operations on the text after the comments in the given filename?

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi: Awesome. Works for me.