# How to append the data from a text file to a list only from a given starting point rather then appending full file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I want to append data from text file to a list from a given starting point. The stating point string can be anywhere in the file. i want to append the data from that starting point. I tried by using *startswith* method:

```
list1=[] 
TextFile = "txtfile.txt"
# open the file for data processing
with open(TextFile,'rt',encoding="utf8") as IpFile:
    for i,j in enumerate(IpFile):
        if(j.startswith("Starting point")):
            list1.append(str(j).strip()) 
            i+=1
```

but it only append the starting point. i want to append the all data from starting point. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean variable

```py
list1=[] 
TextFile = "txtfile.txt"
doAppend = False
# open the file for data processing
with open(TextFile,'rt',encoding="utf8") as IpFile:
    for i,j in enumerate(IpFile):
        if(j.startswith("Starting point")):
            doAppend = True
        if doAppend:
            list1.append(str(j).strip()) 
            i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without a `bool` as well by `break`ing the `for` loop and then reading the rest of the file.

```
list1 = [] 
text_file = "txtfile.txt"
# rt is the default so theres no need to specify it
with open(text_file, encoding="utf8") as ip_file:
    for line in ip_file:
        if line.startswith("Starting point"):
            break
    # read the rest of the file
    remainder = ip_file.read()
    # extend the list with the rest of the file split on newlines
    list1.extend(remainder.split('\n'))
```

Comment: Is it safe to mix iteration with `.read()` like that? Or might the iteration read/buffer in advance and thus the `.read()` might miss some data?

Comment: It depends on how you're using it. In a complex codebase I wouldn't advise it unless you're certain someone isn't going to try and shove logic in between your `read()` and your `break`. In the given example and personal projects it's safe enough. IMO its no different than toying with `.seek()` but I could be wrong.

Comment: Hmm, given that apparently the docs used to say it [does not work right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4762355/12671057), I doubt that it's "safe enough" even for this. Though that's old and I couldn't find something about newer versions, neither that it now "works right" nor that it doesn't.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah, I noticed the link doesn't actually reference what is quoted but you may be onto something. I've seen the given example in the question to consume headers a lot though.

Comment: The link used to actually reference that quote, python.org just defaults to Python 3 now. The [Python 2.7 version](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) of that link still contains that quote.

Comment: @KellyBundy Looking at the source, in Python 3 opening a text file returns and instance of `_io.TextIOWrapper`. The `__next__` method of `_io.TextIOWrapper` just calls `self.readline()`. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f917c243c52d62a787738379fb9b97acbed02c17/Lib/_pyio.py#L2539
So mixing the 2 shouldn't make a difference if you're using Python 3.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the right code (since it's a Python implementation and I'd suspect there to be a C one) and `readline` is not the same as `read`, but I guess if there's a C implementation then it'll be equivalent, and the Python one's `readline` ends with "Rewind _decoded_chars to just after the line ending we found", which sounds good.

Comment: @KellyBundy It's essentially the same thing with the `C` implementation https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f917c243c52d62a787738379fb9b97acbed02c17/Modules/_io/textio.c#L3071 And my point was more that the link calling it into question specifically stated `readline()` can't be used along with iteration when in fact, in Python 3, iteration is just calling `readline()` itself. Either way, it would be nice to have some concrete documentation for Python 3 stating whether you can or can't do it.

Comment: @KellyBundy Here is something more concrete. https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/thread/K6HK4B3SQZVHO3LHSLLI4CKPQIH7BQ5D/#7YXFUXGHUPR574SFWDJ7U5PYUR4WQQ56 

Specifically `I think the 2.x system had an internal buffer that was used by the
file iterator, but not by the file methods. With the new IO stack for
3.0, there is now a common buffer shared by all the file operations
(including iteration).`

Comment: Nice find, thanks. Sounds good, although in the current documentation it would still feel more certain than in an almost 12 years old discussion. Oh well :-)